# How to distinguish which error to throw, authorization or validation?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

In my auth service provider I have checks that throw authorization error, like user attempting to change other users data.

In my controllers I have checks that throw validation error, like certain form parameter is required, and must be an integer.

And I have a few checks in auth service provider that throw authorization error, when for example a user is trying to create an order, without first storing personal data. These checks can easily be changed to throw validation error, instead of authorization. However, I dont know which is "right", or common practice.

How to distinguish which error to throw, authorization or validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to think of authorization as the user having access to do something or not and validation being concerned with the validity of data entered by the user. 
I think it will be an authorization error in your case since the user cannot create an order without first storing personal data. Hence he is not "authorized" to create the order although the data in his order may still be "valid".

Answer (score 0):

Authorization asks the question "is this person allowed to do this" while validation asks "is something wrong in the input?"

Generally you have to be authorised to do something, after which, you can see if the input is valid